# progressbar circle in SherlockActionBar using Fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock, android-progressbar

I have a `SherlockFragmentActivity` using tabhost and viewpager. Calling 
`requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);`

in the fragmentactivity creates the `spinner`, and calling 
`setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);`

won't disable it. I also don't seem to be able to call `getActivity().setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);` 
from the fragments;

I get the error `"The Method setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(boolean) is undefined for the type FragmentActivity."`

What am I doing wrong, can someone show me the way how to use it properly in fragments? I want to be able to create the progressbar in my asynctask pre execute and stop it in postexecute.

I'm using`2.2 emulator` and importing `import com.actionbarsherlock.view.Window;` instead of the android.view one.

[Edit] I just confirmed using setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility works in the 4.1 emulator. Anyway, I need to get this work in 2.2

Comment: You can't use a call that doesn't exist in 2.2. This has no fix except writing that call yourself.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I'd imagine there are a lot of other people wanting to do the same thing, but I'm having trouble finding example code of how it should be done. Any chance of getting an example?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with what `setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility()` does

Comment: "You can't use a call that doesn't exist in 2.2." you can with ActionBarSherlock and the support library in place, hence "setSupportProgressBarVisibility()" rather than  "setProgressBarVisibility()". You have to get ALL the the naming structure switched over though - causing me some headaches this evening :) But god bless Jake Wharton, what a job he's done!

Answer (score 1):

"I also don't seem to be able to call getActivity().setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false); from the fragments;"

You need to be calling getSherlockActivity() instead of getActivity().

"I'm using2.2 emulator and importing import com.actionbarsherlock.view.Window; instead of the android.view one."

Plus one for that, hadn't spotted that import and came across this post which fixed my bug - wasn't showing the progress indicator in Gingerbread before, many thanks :)

Comment: getSherlockActivity() instead of getActivity() that made the trick ;D

Answer (score 0):

This works perfect for me:

```
getActivity().setProgressBarIndeterminate(true);
ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity()); 
progressDialog.show(getActivity(), "This is", " a message...");
```

May you help ;)